# Small errors in my animation

Tags: matlab

```
%Re-setting the MatLab enviroment
close all;
clear all;
clc;
%The box to contain the ball
X = [0 0 5 5 0];
Y = [0 5 5 0 0];
%Declaring the balls initial conditions
initpos.x = rand()*5;
initpos.y = rand()*5;
if 2*initpos.x == initpos.y;
initpos.x = initpos.x + dt;
end
R_Ball = 0.1;
F_Co_eff = 0.85;
initvel = 0.35;
%Conditions to spawn the ball in our box
if initpos.y > 4.9
initpos.y = initpos.y - R_Ball;  
end
if initpos.y < 0.1
initpos.y = initpos.y + R_Ball;  
end
if initpos.x < 0.1
initpos.x = initpos.x + R_Ball;  
end
if initpos.x > 4.9
initpos.x = initpos.x - R_Ball;  
end
%Animation timestep
dt = 0.00125;
%Executing the animation
pos.xy = [initpos.x ; initpos.y];
vel = [initvel ; initvel];
Movement = [1 ; 2].*dt; % Vector to iterate and change the position of the    ball,
%Drawing the first frame
plot(X,Y,'k');
rectangle('position',[initpos.x initpos.y R_Ball R_Ball],'Curvature',[1     1],'FaceColor','b');

while 1
%Updating the ball's position
vel(1) = vel(1) - Movement(1);
vel(2) = vel(2) - Movement(2);
pos.xy(1) = pos.xy(1) + vel(1);
pos.xy(2) = pos.xy(2) + vel(2);
%Maintaining the ball within the axis by changing direction by 90 degrees
%when an axis is hit
if pos.xy(1) > 5 - R_Ball;
vel(1)= (-1)*vel(1);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end
if pos.xy(1) < 0 
vel(1)= (-1)*vel(1);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end
if pos.xy(2) > 5 - R_Ball;
vel(2)= (-1)*vel(2);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end
if pos.xy(2) < 0  
vel(2) = (-1)*vel(2);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end

%Clearing the figure
clf;
%Drawing the frame
plot(X,Y,'k');
rectangle('position', [pos.xy(1) pos.xy(2) R_Ball R_Ball],'Curvature',[1 1],'FaceColor', 'b');
%Setting axis
axis([0 5 0 5]);
axis('equal');   
%Refresh rate
pause(dt)
end
```

Wondering why my program is bugging out I don't see why the ball gravitates to the origin and why it sometimes spawns outside the axis. I'm kind of new so id appreciate it if you could quote the code that's at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your ball goes out of the frame for the first time, you mirror and damp the velocity, but the next position update can still be out of the frame. Therefore you will be mirroring the velocity forever and the ball will never go back in. Try adding conditions over the sign of the velocity, i.e. what direction you are going, like:

```
if vel(1) > 0 && pos.xy(1) > 5 - R_Ball;
vel(1)= (-1)*vel(1);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end
if vel(1) < 0 && pos.xy(1) < 0 
vel(1)= (-1)*vel(1);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end
if vel(2) > 0 && pos.xy(2) > 5 - R_Ball;
vel(2)= (-1)*vel(2);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end
if vel(2) < 0 && pos.xy(2) < 0  
vel(2) = (-1)*vel(2);
vel = (F_Co_eff)*vel;
end
```

About the gravity, it seems that it goes to the origin because you have a tilted gravity vector, try a vertical one:

```
Movement = [0 ; 2].*dt;
```

The path seems then quite natural to me and within the bounds:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the help. Thank you.